# How to add “NEW” badge on latest posts or published 3 days interval

Tags: loop

i make a news blog and i need your help for adding a "new" icon on the automatically inside all loops ( home page - Archive & Latest posts page ) like the photo.[image: "new" icon]

Thanks in advance

here the loop code i'm using for latest posts list

```
<?php
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'posts_per_page' => 6,
       //'offset' => 1 // excludes the first post in the query
   ));
$ids = array();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your "New badge logic" into your loop 
 `while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();` or use [the content filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/). 
There you can use `get_the_date()` function to calculate how old a post is and if it get's an icon or not.

Comment: sorry but im not so good in Php if you can give me more details i will appreciate.